# Map is not show in codeignite

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I actually integrate google map for my site but map is not displayed, I take library googlemaps but still not displayed.
here is my code:

controller:

```
<?php 
 class api extends CI_Controller
 {
     public function index()
     {
         parent::Controller();
     }

    function googleapi()
    {
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        $config = array();
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$config['geocodeCaching'] = TRUE;
$config['region'] = 'US';
$config['sensor'] = FALSE;
$this->googlemaps->create($config);

$markers = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1519';
$marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
$this->googlemaps->add_markers($markers);

$markers = array();
$marker['position'] = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway in Mountain View, Santa Clara County, California United States';
$marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
$this->googlemaps->add_markers($markers);

$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create();

echo print_r($data['map']['markers']);
    }
 }
?>
```

help me if there is something wrong in my code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

Controller File:

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');

$config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1419';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

View File:

```
<html>
<head><?php echo $map['js']; ?></head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
</html>
```